# Shell Script - Loop to make multiples MySQL Query at once

Tags: linux, bash, mysql, shell-script

I've tried to handle this problem, I've a little script to connect into a list of host stored in a file.

```
#!/bin/bash
num=$(wc -l < ip.txt)
while read ip; do
    mysql --login-path=login -h $ip "database" < "query.sql"
    echo "Script 1 - Remaining: "$num $ip
    num=$((num-1))
done < ip.txt
echo "Script 1 Finished!!"
```

I want to run multiple MySQL queries at once for example 10 or 20 so I can finish my test faster, I've tried to make another shell script who runs 4 scripts at once but I really don't know how to handle it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the mysql jobs in the background (by terminating the command with `&`):

```
#!/bin/bash
num=$(wc -l < ip.txt)
while read ip; do
    mysql --login-path=login -h $ip "database" < "query.sql" &
    num=$((num-1))
done < ip.txt
wait
echo "Script 1 Finished!!"
```

The `wait` (a shell builtin command) causes the script to wait until all background jobs have completed.

This is a pretty simple-minded way of doing this, you might want to add logic to put e.g. at most 4 jobs in the background at once.

An alternative is to use [`parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#SYNOPSIS) which works a bit like `xargs` but is designed to run jobs in parallel.